# MySQL Workbench error during dump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'delayed-insert=TRUE'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This is the first time I use MySQL Workbench 6.3, but now I'm facing an error when I export my database. This is the error I get:

```
Running: mysqldump.exe --defaults-file="c:\users\chamro~1\appdata\local\temp\tmp7p3dqt.cnf"  --delayed-insert=TRUE --protocol=tcp --allow-keywords=TRUE --default-character-set=utf8 --host=127.0.0.1 --insert-ignore=TRUE --user=root --complete-insert=TRUE --replace=TRUE --port=3306 --skip-triggers  --no-data  --no-create-db --no-create-info --routines "loansystem"
mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'delayed-insert=TRUE'

Operation failed with exitcode 7
08:18:23 Export of D:\user\Database\Loan Export has finished with 47 errors
```

I've searched a lot but cannot find any help that solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delayed-insert` option has been removed from mysqldump and is no longer accepted. In the latest version of MySQL Workbench (6.3.6 at the time of this writing) this problem is solved.